# Listview layout error

Tags: android, android-listview

I have this listview:

```
@Override
public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSpinner.clearAnimation();
    }
});

// populate list
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Profile profile : friends) {
    //profile.getInstalled();
    values.add(profile.getName());
}

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, final View view, final int i, long i2) {

      Animation pushLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CallActivity.this, R.anim.jump_no_fade);
      view.startAnimation(pushLeftIn);

    }
});

ArrayAdapter<String> friendsListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_items2, values);
friendsListAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);    
    }
});
mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsListAdapter);
}
};
```

and this xml called list_items2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i start up the app and open the listview i get this error in LogCat and it crashes:

```
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2300)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13856)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4424)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4481)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
05-04 14:16:12.911: E/AndroidRuntime(12637):    ... 40 more
```

What i am trying to make is a listview with text and then a image next to the text, and i don't understand why i get this error, any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `ImageView` inside of your `ListView` so you should write a Custom adapter for that ,default `ArrayAdapter` doesn't accept ImageView as ListView resource and it should be just `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a textview id in your layout file.

And use this construct:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```